# NestJS' Logger.error() won't output anything when Nest is started from a Docker container

Tags: nestjs

I did an error filter for my Nest application that outputs my error object with logger.error(). The issue is that logger.error() is not working. I tried to call Logger from multiple locations, nothing worked. The strange part is that other options like verbose and warn work just fine.

Take this code for example:

```js
    import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common'
    export class InstiController{
        constructor(private instiService: InstiService) {}
    
        private logger = new Logger('InstiController')
    
        @Get()
        foo(@GetLoggedUser() user: Usuarios) {
            this.logger.error('This is an error')
            this.logger.warn('This is a warning')
            this.logger.verbose('This is a verbose')
            return this.instiService.listUserInsti(user)
        }
    }
```

Output:

[image]

UPDATE: When I start Nest directly (outside a Docker container) error outputs correctly:
[image]

Comment: Hope you are importing Logger `import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';`

Comment: Yes, I am @TusharRoy. If it was an importing issue I think warn and verbose shouldn't work as well. 

I'm also not customizing the implementation of Base Logger so it shouldn't be an issue with a conflicting custom implementation.

Comment: Is there any logger options set in `main.ts`? If yes, try to remove it and test again.

Comment: @MicFung no, there isn't. I also disabled a Logging interceptor I had just in case, still not working.

Comment: weird. Is it possible for you to push the code to github for us to see?

Comment: @MicFung check my update, when I start Nest outside a docker container Logger.error() simply works.

Comment: cool. i will test it on docker and see how the log works there. you serve the dist folder in docker ?

Comment: just tested with docker. it can show the error message as well. can you share your Dockerfile as well? and docker-compose if any

Comment: I can simulate it if I read the log from docker GUI instead of running docker logs command. Can you try `docker logs <container_name> -f` and see if you can find error log.

Comment: @MicFung it works, error is displayed using this command. Someone on Nest's discord explained: logger.error outputs to stderr, which you might not be seeing from the docker container, you may only be looking at stdout.

I wonder if there is a setting to display stderr from the GUI.

Comment: I find a way to show it on GUI. please wait, i need to capture the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mic Fung solutions should work in theory however it still didn't work for me. I noticed my other computer (using Docker Desktop 3.3.2 and docker engine 20.10.5 was displaying error logs just fine).

So, I assumed the issue was specific to 3.3.3 and updated Docker Desktop to 3.4.0. Now my issue is fixed. Error messages display again and it didn't require any new configuration

Answer (score 2):

The default docker GUI logging level is info so the error log is not showing.

To override the logging level, go to

1. setting
2. Docker Engine
3. add `"logging": "fatal"`
4. Apply & Restart
5. Remove the affected container
6. Rebuild it via Dockerfile or docker-compose

The error log should be able to show.

P.S. The logging level in docker GUI is ("debug"|"info"|"warn"|"error"|"fatal") (default "info")

[image]

Image from Docker GUI after setting logging level:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/v64OS.png

---

**Way 02:**

add log level setting though `command` in `docker-compose.yml`.

Then, remove the container and rebuild it with docker-compose up -d

```
...
services:
      xxx:
        build:
            context: .
            target: development
            dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
        command:
            - "--log.level=FATAL"
....
```

Comment: Did you change any other setting? I added "log-level": "fatal" but it's still not logging error.

I'm using docker-compose, I wonder if this can affect the setting.

Comment: No. only set the log-level.

Comment: are you using windows or mac or linux? I use docker-compose as well

Comment: I'm using Windows, I also set debug to true just in case, still didn't work.

Comment: I don't have Windows to test with, maybe try to remove the container and let's the docker-compose to build it again. I think Windows is not smart enough to rebuild it automatically.

Comment: I find another way you can test with. see the updated answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, your solutions didn't work for me. I updated my Docker Desktop from 3.3.3 to 3.4.0. It now uses Docker engine 20.10.7 instead of 20.10.6 and the error messages work again. My other computer was on 3.3.2 and error logs also works, which makes me believe this was an issue with 3.3.3. Anyway, my issue is solved now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting it manually while bootstrapping.

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
  logger: ['error', 'warn'],
});
```

Values in the array can be any combination of 'log', 'error', 'warn', 'debug', and 'verbose'.

Comment: Already did that but still no output. And I know manually setting in the bootstrapping is working because if I remove 'warn' or 'verbose' from this array the respective outputs from my example code also vanish.

Comment: Check my updated post, when I start Nest outside a Docker container error works just fine.